# Invent stopped custom thread through decorator, but problems occured with passing parameters to annotation or calling an annotated function

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading, python-multithreading, python-decorators

I have created a class with a wrapper function for executing them in a separate thread. I want to stop the thread by the appropriate flag. But I can't call my threadable function. I don't understand which parameters i need to pass into decorator or/and function.

```
#/usr/bin/python3
import threading

class ThreadedFunction():
    def threaded(fn, callback_func, isStop):
        """To use as decorator to make a function call threaded.
        It will call the callback_func when the function returns.
        Needs import
        from threading import Thread"""
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            def do_callback():
                callback_func(fn(args, kwargs))
            thread = threading.Thread(target=do_callback)
            thread.start()
            if isStop:
                print("Exit from thread")
                thread._stop()
            return thread
        return wrapper

    @threaded
    def wannaThread(self, isStop):
        while isStop != True:
             print("I want to run this in separate thread!")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    tfunction = ThreadedFunction.wannaThread(True)
    tfunction = ThreadedFunction.wannaThread(False)
```

output is:

```
TypeError: threaded() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'callback_func' and 'isStop'
```

How to correctly pass parameters to annotation or call a function? How to stop the thread correctly? Thank you for you time!